# Hawaii template Categories Sidebar Menu

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to have the categories sidebar menu start in the expanded state? Currently it starts out collapsed and requires the user to expand the top level categories to view the ones underneath.

My store has only one main category right now and I would like to have it expanded unless the user chooses to collapse it

here is a link to the demo page as my site has not been published yet.
http://hawaii-demo.mybigcommerce.com/

[[image: This is how I would like the sidebar navigation to appear]

Comment: Anybody have a thought on this. not sure why I get a down vote for a question that wasn't answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since the category list is controlled by a snippet, you would need to use javascript to autoselect/autoexpand that particular parent category.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('li:contains(parentCategoryName)').hasClass('expandable') {
    $(this).addClass('collapsable');
    $(this).removeClass('expandable');
}
else {
    return null;
}
});
```

I haven't tested the above script, but that would be one of my first tries. It may require tweaks. You should replace "parentCategoryName" with the name of your parent category that you want to expand.